# Property Proxy not supported. Blazor Client Side MS Graph API

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, blazor

I am trying to retrieve user groups from Microsoft's Graph API based on an access token retrieved in a Blazor Client-Side app.

Index.razor.cs partial.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Linq;

namespace blazorapp.Pages
{
    public partial class Index
    {
        [Inject]
        IAccessTokenProvider TokenProvider { get; set; }
        protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            var tokenResult = await TokenProvider.RequestAccessToken(
            new AccessTokenRequestOptions
            {
                Scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/GroupMember.Read.All" }
            });

            if (tokenResult.TryGetToken(out var token))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(token.Value);
                try
                {
                    var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider((requestMessage) =>
                    {
                        requestMessage
                            .Headers
                            .Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token.Value);
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }));
                    var securityEnabledOnly = true;
                    var groupsRequest = await graphServiceClient
                        .Me
                        .GetMemberGroups(securityEnabledOnly)
                        .Request()
                        .PostAsync();
                } catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It returns the token fine, and when used in jwt.ms or postman it returns fine. However in the browser I am getting

"Property Proxy is not supported." from the Console log inside my catch block. Is there an obvious error in my code that might be causing this issue?

Comment: can you please share the code snippet where you are using proxy

Answer (score 2):

When you create GraphServiceClient, the client is using GraphClientFactory to construct a HttpClient optimized for Graph API. The factory then inspects and uses bunch of properties (like Proxy) which are not supported by blazor HttpClient.

You need to provide your own client to work around this.

```
var graphHttpClient = new HttpClient(); // example, get your own client properly
var authenticationProvider = new DelegateAuthenticationProvider((requestMessage) => 
{
    requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token.Value);
    return Task.FromResult(0);
});

var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(graphHttpClient);
graphServiceClient.AuthenticationProvider = authenticationProvider;
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I've been struggling to find any documentation about how to use the GraphServiceClient with Blazor WASM!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. You can do the following:

```
var serviceGraph = new GraphServiceClient(injectedHttpClient);
serviceGraph.AuthenticationProvider = new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(request =>
{
   request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token.Value);
   return Task.FromResult(0);
});

var result = await serviceGraph.Me.Request().GetAsync();
```

There is an overloaded constructor in GraphServiceClient that accepts HttpClient, the one that Blazor WebAssembly uses to make requests to Web API. Then with that object, you can set AuthenticationProvider just like Peter demonstrated.

I am using Microsoft Graph v3.8.0.