# GraphServiceClient: Operation is not supported on this platform (using Blazor - Microsoft Graph)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, blazor, graphserviceclient

I'm trying to do the following in Blazor:

```
public GraphServiceClient GraphClient { get; set; } = new(new AccessTokenProviderTokenCredential(AccessTokenProvider));
```

But I have the following error message:

[image]

Is GraphServiceClient not allowed in Blazor? Or am I doing something wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: Could you pls let us know if you had a standalone blazor WASM or an asp.net core hosted blazor Wasm?

Comment: Standalone Blazor.

Comment: Actually I can only provide a sample.... Per my knowledge, since your app is a stand alone wasm, so you can't use credential flow to generate access token, in other words, you have to integrate azure ad to let users sign in your app with MSAL first then you can based on the authentication info to generate access token. My code below based on the [official code sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code#single-page-applications).

Comment: pls note, since it is stand-alone wasm, you need to set the redirect url in `Single-page application` platform(you need to go to azure ad-> authentication to set redirect url). And pls don't forget to pick the option Access token and ID token check box in `Implicit grant and hybrid flows`(also in azure ad-> authentication blade)

Answer (score 1):

The default `HttpProvider` is not supported in Blazor. You can use GraphServiceClient if you provide your own `IHttpProvider` or use the constructor that takes a `HttpClient`.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62957206/906773) for how to use the constructor with `HttpClient`.

You can find [an example here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/graph-api?view=aspnetcore-6.0) for settings up your own `IHttpProvider`. Posted it below in case the link changes:

```
private class HttpClientHttpProvider : IHttpProvider
{
    private readonly HttpClient http;

    public HttpClientHttpProvider(HttpClient http)
    {
        this.http = http;
    }

    public ISerializer Serializer { get; } = new Serializer();

    public TimeSpan OverallTimeout { get; set; } = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300);

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        return http.SendAsync(request);
    }

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, 
        HttpCompletionOption completionOption, 
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return http.SendAsync(request, completionOption, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Then in your constructor pass it in as the second argument:

```
public GraphServiceClient GraphClient { get; set; } = 
new(new AccessTokenProviderTokenCredential(AccessTokenProvider), HttpProvider);
                                                                 ^
                                                                 Here
```

The reason your current code is not working is becase it is calling the 
[following code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/7f9b8ce5a0d847feab022be1786486bb3432ffd0/src/libraries/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/BrowserHttpHandler/BrowserHttpHandler.cs#L51-L131) in `BrowserHttpHandler` because that is used when you do not specify a HttpProvider.

```
public IWebProxy? Proxy
{
    get => throw new PlatformNotSupportedException();
    set => throw new PlatformNotSupportedException();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, pls follow [this sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-blazor-wasm/tree/main/WebApp-OIDC/MyOrg/blazorwasm-singleOrg) to integrate azure ad to your stand-alone blazor wasm app, don't forget to modify the `wwroot/appsetting.json` with the azure ad app information.

Then we can try to use graph sdk to call ms graph api based on the authentication. Here's [another sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-blazor-wasm/tree/main/WebApp-graph-user/Call-MSGraph) for it. But it has some differences per my test.

First let's add a navigation into NavMenu.razor:

```
<li class="nav-item px-3">
   <NavLink class="nav-link" href="/profile" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
       <span class="oi oi-person" aria-hidden="true"></span> Profile
   </NavLink>
</li>
```

Then add `UserProfile.razor` and `UserProfileBase.cs` for using graph SDK to call graph api and show it.

```
@page "/profile"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@attribute [Authorize]
@inherits UserProfileBase

<h3>User Profile</h3>
@{
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Property</th>
                <th>Value</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr>
            <td> DisplayName </td>
            <td> @_user.DisplayName </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> UserPrincipalName </td>
            <td> @_user.UserPrincipalName </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
 }
```

and `UserProfileBase.cs`：

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace blazorwasm_singleOrg.Pages
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Base class for UserProfile component.
    /// Injects GraphServiceClient and calls Microsoft Graph /me endpoint.
    /// </summary>
    public class UserProfileBase : ComponentBase
    {
        [Inject]
        GraphServiceClient GraphClient { get; set; }

        protected User _user = new User();
        protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            await GetUserProfile();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Retrieves user information from Microsoft Graph /me endpoint.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private async Task GetUserProfile()
        {
            try
            {
                var request = GraphClient.Me.Request();
                _user = await request.GetAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then create `GraphClientExtensions.cs` in Data folder:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication;
using Microsoft.Authentication.WebAssembly.Msal.Models;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace blazorwasm_singleOrg.Pages.Data
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Adds services and implements methods to use Microsoft Graph SDK.
    /// </summary>
    internal static class GraphClientExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Extension method for adding the Microsoft Graph SDK to IServiceCollection.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="services"></param>
        /// <param name="scopes">The MS Graph scopes to request</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static IServiceCollection AddMicrosoftGraphClient(this IServiceCollection services, params string[] scopes)
        {
            services.Configure<RemoteAuthenticationOptions<MsalProviderOptions>>(options =>
            {
                foreach (var scope in scopes)
                {
                    options.ProviderOptions.AdditionalScopesToConsent.Add(scope);

                }
            });

            services.AddScoped<IAuthenticationProvider, GraphAuthenticationProvider>();
            services.AddScoped<IHttpProvider, HttpClientHttpProvider>(sp => new HttpClientHttpProvider(new HttpClient()));
            //services.AddScoped<GraphServiceClient>();
            services.AddScoped(sp => {
                return new GraphServiceClient(
                  sp.GetRequiredService<IAuthenticationProvider>(),
                  sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpProvider>());
            });
            return services;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Implements IAuthenticationProvider interface.
        /// Tries to get an access token for Microsoft Graph.
        /// </summary>
        private class GraphAuthenticationProvider : IAuthenticationProvider
        {
            public GraphAuthenticationProvider(IAccessTokenProvider provider)
            {
                Provider = provider;
            }

            public IAccessTokenProvider Provider { get; }

            public async Task AuthenticateRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
            {
                var result = await Provider.RequestAccessToken(new AccessTokenRequestOptions()
                {
                    Scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read" }
                });

                if (result.TryGetToken(out var token))
                {
                    request.Headers.Authorization ??= new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token.Value);
                }
            }
        }

        private class HttpClientHttpProvider : IHttpProvider
        {
            private readonly HttpClient _client;

            public HttpClientHttpProvider(HttpClient client)
            {
                _client = client;
            }

            public ISerializer Serializer { get; } = new Serializer();

            public TimeSpan OverallTimeout { get; set; } = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300);

            public void Dispose()
            {
            }

            public Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
            {
                return _client.SendAsync(request);
            }

            public Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                return _client.SendAsync(request, completionOption, cancellationToken);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in Program.cs, add the service before the line `builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication`:

`builder.Services.AddMicrosoftGraphClient("https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read");`

The nuget packages installed:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="3.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Build" Version="3.2.1" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="3.2.1" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Authentication.WebAssembly.Msal" Version="3.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph" Version="3.16.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http.Json" Version="3.2.0" />
```

[image]